# A PHP Error was encountered - Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch data from my database to a data table with table headers "Total No. of Students | Male | Female"

This is the error it showed

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$totalcount
>
> Filename: pages/studentgender.php
>
> Line Number: 20
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\libsystem\application\views\pages\studentgender.php
>       Line: 20
>       Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\libsystem\application\controllers\Students.php
>       Line: 30
>       Function: view

This is my model

```
public function studentCountGender(){
    $this->db->select('studgender, COUNT(*) as totalcount, COUNT(   case when studgender = "Male" then 1 else 0 end)
                        AS malecount, COUNT(    case when studgender = "Female" then 1 else 0 end) AS femalecount');
    $this->db->from('student');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

This is my controller

```
 public function studentList(){

    $this->load->model('student_model');
    $data['result'] = $this->student_model->studentCountGender();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('pages/studentgender', $data);
}
```

This is my view

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Total No. of Students</th>
            <th>Total Number of Males</th>
            <th>Total Number of Females</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php
    foreach($sample as $item){
      echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$item->totalcount.'</td>
        <td>'.$item->malecount.'</td>
        <td>'.$item->femalecount.'</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    ';}?>
</table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me how to parse it and it will not show the error? I've been trying to debug this for 2 hours and it's making me insane thanks alot!!!

Comment: From where did you bring `$sample`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: can you paste query result here ?

Comment: replace $sample  with $data['result'] . I hope it will work.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the right controller method. Also make sure you're not overwriting the value of $data['result'] somewhere.

Comment: just do var_dump($data), You will get an idea

Answer (score 3):

Try this code once.

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $item){
      echo "<tr>
         <td>{$item->totalcount}</td>
          <td>{$item->malecount}</td>
         <td>{$item->femalecount}</td>
        </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view use $result rather than $sample hope this will work

Comment: changed it to $result but it showed Message: Undefined variable: result

Answer (score 0):

You are passing  `$data['result']` to the view , Then how do you get result in `$sample` as `$item` in `foreach`. Please check again.

Comment: changed it to $result but it showed Message: Undefined variable: result

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code hope this help you. may you don't have the result or pass the $data in incorrect view please check accordingly.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($result)&& !empty($result)){
            foreach($result as $item){
              echo "<tr>
                 <td>".$item->totalcount."</td>
                  <td>".$item->malecount;"</td>
                 <td>".$item->femalecount."</td>
                </tr>";
            }
    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will work for you.

Your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('student_model');
}

public function studentList(){
    $data = [];
    $data['result'] = $this->student_model->studentCountGender();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('pages/studentgender', $data);
}
```

Your model:

```
<?
public function studentCountGender(){
    $this->db->select('studgender, COUNT(*) as totalcount, COUNT(   case when studgender = "Male" then 1 else 0 end)
                        AS malecount, COUNT(    case when studgender = "Female" then 1 else 0 end) AS femalecount');
    $this->db->from('student');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Your view:

```
foreach($result as $item){
      echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$item->totalcount.'</td>
        <td>'.$item->malecount.'</td>
        <td>'.$item->femalecount.'</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    }
```

Greetings!